# How to make this simple java code into a while loop and has an option to end program or restart again?

Tags: java

Please help me do this code into a while loop and has an option to restart or end the program.
I'm really bad at doing while loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CC131 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter any character: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = in.nextLine();
        count(z);
    }
    public static void count(String x) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] ch = x.toCharArray();
        int letter = 0;
        int space = 0;
        int num = 0;
        int other = 0;  
        int ctr=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ch[i])){
                System.out.println("This is an alphabet.");
            }
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
                System.out.println("This is a digit.");
            }
            else if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch[i])) {
                System.out.println("This is a whitespace.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This is an another character.");    
            }

            System.out.println("Type 1 to restart program, otherwise type anything to exit.");
            int d = in.nextInt();
            if (d==1) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("System will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you'd like to achieve. Why are you prompting the user for a single character, then reading an entire line of input and iterating over it? Do you know that you're prompting the user to exit the program for every character in their original message?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this as a student. I was asked to make a program that would identify the user input's character if it's a whitespace, letter or a number or a special character. I would like the user of the program to have an option to re-enter again another input and have the option to exit the program.

Comment: No problem! I'm only asking so that you're able to get better help. I'm currently busy at the moment so I can't help much. PS, you probably want to keep count of your spaces etc. e.g. `if (isSpaceChar...) spaces++;`

Comment: I think he wants to restart this program which means he wants to run main function again and again when he pressed 1

Comment: @kalana yes exactly. Really noob at this bec. our former prof didn't really teach us how to do stuff. I rely mostly on youtube tutorials and w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call main function in another function luckily it is possible thing.

- If you want to run main method continuously when press 1 use this code

```
    int d = in.nextInt();
    if (d==1) {
       CC131.main(null);
    }
```

- second thing is you can only use numbers to stop this program because you have used `int` type variable to give input. There for your full code should be

```
    System.out.println("Type 1 to restart program, otherwise type **any number** to exit.");
    int d = in.nextInt();
    if (d==1) {
         CC131.main(null);
    }
    else {
         System.out.println("System will now exit.");
         System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want your program to continue operating if the user didn't enter 1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CC131 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter any character: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = in.nextLine();
        while(true){
           count(z);
        }
    }
    public static void count(String x) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] ch = x.toCharArray();
        int letter = 0;
        int space = 0;
        int num = 0;
        int other = 0;  
        int ctr=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ch[i])){
                System.out.println("This is an alphabet.");
            }
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
                System.out.println("This is a digit.");
            }
            else if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch[i])) {
                System.out.println("This is a whitespace.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This is an another character.");    
            }

            System.out.println("Type 1 to restart program, otherwise type anything to exit.");
            int d = in.nextInt();
            if (d != 1) {
                System.out.println("System will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close. Think about separation of responsibility. Think about this problem like you're writing a miniature operating system. When your OS starts you will want it to continue running. In order to stay running you will want what we call a flag. Let's name it something like 'keepRunning'. You'll want to continue to check this after every analysis to see if the user wants to keep running.

Everything you want running will stay in your while loop.

Since you are new I've added a few more improvements to the code. Use methods so you can write more meaningful code. This way you can start separating your code blocks with meaningful method signatures.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CC131 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }

    public static void run(){
        boolean keepRunning = true;
        while(keepRunning){
            String input = getInput();
            analyzeInput(input);

            if(!shouldKeepRunning()){
                System.out.println("System will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getInput() {
        System.out.print("Please enter any character: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        return in.next();
    }

    public static void analyzeInput(String input) {
        Character character = input.toCharArray()[0];
        if (Character.isLetter(character)) {
            System.out.println("This is an alphabet.");
        } else if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
            System.out.println("This is a digit.");
        } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(character)) {
            System.out.println("This is a whitespace.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is an another character.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean shouldKeepRunning(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to analyze a different character? y/n");
        String input = in.next();
        return input.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
    }

}
```